# ExecutorService slow performance in Java EE7 container

Tags: multithreading, performance, jakarta-ee, executorservice, glassfish-4

I've got a test EE7 application where a servlet invokes an EJB that runs a threaded set of tasks using an ExecutorService.  Compared to a bog-standard java console app running the same set of tasks, the performance (transactions per second) is way off - 2.5k tps in the console app vs 50 tps in the EE app (both are tested with 256 threads calling the code repeatedly for 60s, the EE app done via SoapUI).

The tasks are just dummy implementations that sleep for 100ms.  In the test, five parallel tasks are submitted; timings show these all complete in 100-101ms as expected - Glassfish+Servlet+EJB really don't seem to add much overhead at all.

I've done the same test under both Windows and Linux with the same results.  In both cases, I'm using Glassfish 4.0 with the default ManagedExecutorService.  I've increased the max connections/cache/bean/thread/etc settings to 256.

NB: if I just invoke the EJB but don't submit anything to the ExecutorService, I get 9k tps.  If I take the wait out of the tasks, I get 5k tps.  My machine never seems to be running out of recources (cpu cores average between 10-25%, with system memory to spare (haven't tuned the jvm)).

I appreciate this is a bit vague, but do you think this is more an issue with the configuration of Glassfish, or running managed threads in Java EE7?  I was hoping for at least 1k tps from Glassfish, and hoping for 2k.

**UPDATE**: I've tried JBoss' Wildfly 8 beta, and I'm getting about 5k tps - a massive difference.

To recreate from code below: create an EE app in Netbeans 7.4 targetting Glassfish 4/EE7, then add Servlet and EJB.

The EJB + Task class:

```
package ejb;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.*;
import javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class NewSessionBean {
    @Resource(name="concurrent/__defaultManagedExecutorService")
    ManagedExecutorService executor;    

    public String businessMethod() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String message = "<p>starting businessMethod()</p>";

        List<MyTask> tasks = new ArrayList<MyTask>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            MyTask task = new MyTask(String.format("Task %d \r\n", i));
            tasks.add(task);
        }

        List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
        int taskCount = tasks.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++) {
            MyTask task = tasks.get(i);
            if(task != null) {
                 futures.add(executor.submit(task));
            }
        }

        int futureCount = futures.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < futureCount; i++) {
            Future<String> future = futures.get(i);
            if(future != null) {
                try {
                    message += future.get();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    message += ex.getMessage();
                    Logger.getLogger(NewSessionBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                    message += ex.getMessage();
                    Logger.getLogger(NewSessionBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        message += String.format("<p>took %d ms (started at %d)</p>", end-start, start);

        return message;
    }
}

class MyTask implements Callable<String> {
    String message;

    public MyTask(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        if(message == null) message = "";

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        message += String.format("<p>thread %s</p>", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        message += String.format("<p>started at %d</p>", start);

        Thread.sleep(100);

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        message += String.format("<p>ended at %d (duration = %d ms)</p>", end, end-start);

        return message;
    }    
}
```

The Servlet:

```
package servlet;

import java.io.*;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    ejb.NewSessionBean nsb;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet NewServlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet NewServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println(nsb.businessMethod());
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
}
```

Comment: You pointed yourself to an answer by switching containers; though, I wonder why is the difference so massive?  ManagedExecutorService even with 256 was likely not configured correctly.  How would the mechanics of ManagedExecutorService differ in the two containers?  In weblogic there is the concept of WorkManagers; could such a server-specific setting be throttling Glassfish?  Could you observe using top or taskmanager or a server-specific monitoring tool the creation of all thread?